# Location does not get displayed in bibliography with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, apa-style

I have a problem with my bibliography. Whenever a book gets cited it does not print the location in the bibliography, even though  the information is in the .bib file. Here is a short version of my actual code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,american]{report}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=black,filecolor=black,citecolor=black]{hyperref}


\addbibresource{doc.bib}

\begin{document}
    
Hello \autocite{Andresen2020} \textcite{Anselin1988} and \autocite{Akers2012}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

An here is the bib file:

```
@book{Akers2012,
author = {Ronald L. Akers},
   location = {New York, NY and Abington, Oxon},
   doi = {10.4324/9781315062723},
   edition = {2},
   editor = {Ronald L. Akers},
   journal = {Criminological Theories: Introduction and Evaluation},
   publisher = {Routledge},
   title = {Criminological theories: Introduction and evaluation},
   year = {2012},
}

@book{Andresen2020,
    author = {Martin A Andresen},
    location = {Abington, Oxon and New York, NY},
    edition = {2},
    isbn = {9781138316980},
    publisher = {Routledge},
    title = {Environmental Criminology: Evolution, Theory, and Practice},
    year = {2020},
}

@book{Anselin1988,
    author = {Luc Anselin},
    location = {Dordrecht},
    publisher = {Kluwer Academic},
    title = {Spatial Econometrics: Methods and Models},
    year = {1988},
}
```

An here how my bibliography looks after compiling:
[image: bibliography]

I am on macOS 11.5.2 and everything LaTeX-related should be up to date. I have looked at the biblatex documentation but did not find any solution yet.. I am thankful for any kind of advise!

Answer (score 2):

`biblatex-apa`'s `style=apa,` in a current version (>=9.0) implements APA style according to the 7th edition of the APA manual.

In 7th-edition APA style the location is not shown for books and similar works (see e.g.
https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/references/elements-list-entry#source)

> A location is not required in the source element for most works (e.g., do not include the publisher location for book references).

See also the various examples in https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/references/examples/book-references.

In that respect the output you are getting is correct current (7th edition) APA style.

---

Note that in `Akers2012` there is no reason to also list Akers as the editor of the work.

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Akers2012,
  author    = {Ronald L. Akers},
  title     = {Criminological Theories},
  subtitle  = {Introduction and Evaluation},
  year      = {2012},
  edition   = {2},
  doi       = {10.4324/9781315062723},
  publisher = {Routledge},
  location  = {New York, NY and Abington, Oxon},
}
@book{Andresen2020,
  author    = {Martin A. Andresen},
  title     = {Environmental Criminology},
  subtitle  = {Evolution, Theory, and Practice},
  year      = {2020},
  edition   = {2},
  isbn      = {9781138316980},
  publisher = {Routledge},
  location  = {Abington, Oxon and New York, NY},
}
@book{Anselin1988,
  author    = {Luc Anselin},
  title     = {Spatial Econometrics},
  subtitle  = {Methods and Models},
  year      = {1988},
  publisher = {Kluwer Academic},
  location  = {Dordrecht},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{Akers2012,Andresen2020,Anselin1988}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Akers, R. L. (2012). Criminological theories: Introduction and evaluation (2nd ed.). Routledge. https://doi.org/10.4324/9781315062723 Andresen, M. A. (2020). Environmental criminology: Evolution, theory, and practice (2nd ed.). Routledge. Anselin, L. (1988). Spatial econometrics: Methods and models. Kluwer Academic.]